# Why is res.render in Angular Universal taking so long?

Tags: node.js, angular, express, angular-universal, angular5

I am building a Angular Universal App and all i have now is the Structure of the site. I did everything like in the tutorial concerning transforming my app for Angular Universal.

```js
console.log("got Request " + new Date());
res.render(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser', 'index.html'), { req , time: true}, 
   function(err, html) {
      console.log("finished Rendering " + new Date());
      res.send(html);
   }   
);
```

The Rendering takes up 3 and a half seconds.. This seems like a huge amount of time to me. Also in the DeveloperTools in Chrome TTFB is 3,5 seconds.
And the app doesnt do anything yet except routing. I dont want  my future app to be so slow.

Anyone has a clue if this is normal or there is something to improve ?
Github repo with Problem  https://github.com/Joniras/slow-universal-rendering-example

**Setting up Workspace and running angular-universal:**

```
npm install   
npm run build:universal   
npm run serve:universal
```

> **Versions:**
>   `Angular CLI: 1.5.0`
>   `Node: 6.11.5`
>   `OS: win32 x64`
>   `Angular: 5.0.1`
>   `... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms`
>   `... http, language-service, platform-browser`
>   `... platform-browser-dynamic, platform-server, router`
>   `@angular/cdk: 5.0.0-rc0`
>   `@angular/cli: 1.5.0`
>   `@angular/flex-layout: 2.0.0-beta.10-4905443`
>   `@angular/material: 5.0.0-rc0`
>   `@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.33`
>   `@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.20`
>   `@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.35`
>   `@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0`
>   `@ngtools/webpack: 1.8.0`
>   `@schematics/angular: 0.1.3`
>   `typescript: 2.4.2`
>   `webpack: 3.8.1`
>   `express 4.16.2`
>   **i had to style as code because otherwise i couldnt post**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a 3000 ms timeout in your code (UserService)

```
setTimeout(() => {
          resolve(this.loggedInUser);
        }, 3000);
```

Comment: @Ayyash setTimeout is a javascript api, and can be used on both browser as well as node server
https://nodejs.org/de/docs/guides/timers-in-node/