# Angular Universal + Express Server took a long time to first response

Tags: node.js, express, angular-universal, server-side-rendering

I use SSR in angular 2 app with Angular Universal.

this caused 5 second response time to my express server! am i doing something wrong??

it's like node hanged in rendering process.

[image]

Comment: Make sure you don't have a setTimeout somewhere... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47304845/why-is-res-render-in-angular-universal-taking-so-long.